# How do you regenerate all 2-of-2 multisig addresses from two xPrivkeys?

Tags: private-key, public-key, address-generation, bip32-hd-wallets, multi-signature

If I want to get the private and public keys of all transactions that have happened on my multisig wallet. How would I do that?

It's a 2-of-2 multisig setup. I have an `xPrivkey` on my computer and an `xPrivkey` on my phone. 
How do I combine these keys to generate the list of private keys and the corresponding list of public keys.

The purpose would be to redeem my BCH.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to generate all possible combinations would probably go on forever. I would suggest you figure out what the derivation path used on you BCH wallet was (will probably be `/m/44'/145'/0'`) and then loop through different combinations to generate different multisig addresses.

How come you only have the xPrivkeys and not the mnemonic words?

If you had the mnemonic words I would suggest recreating the wallet *on the same wallet app* by importing your seeds and the wallet should scan addresses associated with those keys.